# Как получить код на основе GUI - формы в Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, gui, intellij-idea

Чтобы создать `GUI` я использовал редактор форм в `Intellij IDEA`.
`GUI` (без подключения Listener'ов) я создал.
Там был у меня файл в составе GUI формы и коротенького java класса, с объявлением контейнера формы и компонентов (практически без методов).  Скрины (для наглядности прикрепляю).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: можно ли в Intellij IDEA  на основе GUI-Формы,  сгенирировать код, такой чтобы можно его было редактировать, добавлять листенеры и т.п.? Если можно, то как?

**P.S.** Мануал Давыдов-Ефимов по Intellij IDEA читал и ни понял как это сделать.

Comment: Если это важно, версия IDEA 14 Ultimate (т.е. там эта опция быть должна).

Comment: Разве *SimGUI.java* не то, что вам надо? Это класс, сгенерированный на основе формы - можете его редактировать, добавлять листенеры и т.п.

Comment: @ pavlofff Ну там нет свойств компонент, таких как размеры, название кнопок, цвет и т.д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

См. меню `File->Settings->Editor->GUIDesigner->Generate GUI into:...` Поставьте "`Java source code`"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого скомпилируйте программу.

Comment: поставил. Где мой код теперь?

Comment: Всё разобрался. Спасибо. И откуда вы всё это знаете?