# Как добавить в программу графический компонент, созданный в intelliJ через new -> GUI Form

Tags: java, gui, form

Есть написанная программа со стантадтной библиотекой Swing, для изменения одного визуального компонента, наследника JComponent решил упростить себе жизнь и воспользоваться встроенным в іdea плагином, создал new - > GUI form, настроил оформление компонента (два файла, один java, другой XML c разметкой формы), но вот как использовать этот компонент в приложении ума не приложу, как заставить программу прорисовать этот компонент. Помещаться он должен в программе на JPanel. Подскажите, возможно следует переопределить определенный метод, или в конструкторе указать каким-то образом прорисовку. Или это первоначально тупиковый путь, и при использовании GUI Form нужно писать всю программу, а отдельный компонент невозможно?

Answer (score 1):

После того, как вы разметили форму и сгенерировали файл java, следует зайти в этот файл и дописать после описания класса `extends` и нужный вам класс. Например `extends JPanel`. После этого вы можете создать экземпляр этого класса и обращаться с ним так же как с `JPanel`. Например вставить в другую панель вашей формы.

Comment: extends JComponent я написал, программа компилится проблема не в этом, а в том что в класс при построении GUI form через intellij добавляются компоненты, но они никак не отображаются в приложении, вышел из положения по другому, при построении GUI формы создается базовая панель, на которой размещаются все компоненты. так вот в базовую программу следует добавлять не сам компонент, а эту самую базовую панель, в этом случаи все нормально видно, хотя и переписать немного приложеньку придется

Comment: @ЮрийЯхница может элементы добавляются, но сам компонент не верно определяет свои размеры при выводе на форму и появляется с минимальными размерами? Что если попробовать явно задать ему размеры через setBounds?

Comment: Как вариант проблема в размерах, или в координата, может он строится за пределами приложения. Факт в том, что специально скомпилировал весь java код построения приложения, копировал его в новый класс и в этом классе все отлично прорисовывается, а в классе где весь этот код создается ничего не работает. Уже голову себе сломал как с ним работать в нормальном режиме. Стоит обучалку минимальную пройти по созданию форм в idea, меньше будет вопросов.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решил прочитав по этой ссылке [как получить код на основе GUI Form](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/465289/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5-gui-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B2-intellij-idea)

все дело в том, что Idea генерирует внутреннюю JPanel  на которой размещаются все элементы, просто в конструкторе стоит добавить эту панель к нашему новому компоненту (соответственно наследовавшисть от JPanel или JComponent) и к всему прочьему в самом конструкторе уже возможно поменять заголовки всех компонентов, установить слушателей и прочье, наковырялся но слава богу разобрался, теперь можно использовать редактор форм на свое усмотрение