# Редактирования GUI swing из созданного ранее класса созданого без использования gui designer intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, swing, gui

Есть несколько классов содержащих графический интерфейс написан вручную можно как-то в сделать в intellij idea чтобы это все что написано вручною превратилось в констуктор gui designer intellij idea?

Comment: Возможно, [это поможет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/465289/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5-gui-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B2-intellij-idea)

Comment: Нет мне нужно класс который был написан не в  intellij idea перевести в редактор формы  intellij idea

Comment: Тогда что за GUI-классы, где, как и кем написаны? Добавьте это в вопрос.